# Why am I getting blank strings here?

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string by individual newlines or groups of spaces. I got the result, except for `''` strings. How do I eliminate those?

Edit: I need the output to retain whitespace groups and split on each newline. The only unwanted things are the `''`.

```
In [208]: re.split('(\n|\ +)', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi')
Out[208]: 
['many',
 '   ',
 'fancy',
 ' ',
 'word',
 ' ',
 '',
 '\n',
 '',
 '\n',
 '',
 '    ',
 'hello',
 '    ',
 '\t',
 '   ',
 'hi']
```

Comment: Because `()` is a *capture group*. Define it as a *non capture group* with `(?:\n|\ +)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry I didnt make my requirement clear. Please see update.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/MB5TQ3, use `[x for x in re.split('(\n| +)', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi') if x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern include capturing group, those separators are included in the result list.

If you don't use the capturing group or replacing the capturing group (`(...)`) with non-capturing group (`(?:...)`), the separators are not included.

```
# Not using group at all
>>> re.split('\n|\ +', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi')
['many', 'fancy', 'word', '', '', '', 'hello', '\t', 'hi']


# Using non-capturing group
>>> re.split('(?:\n|\ +)', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi')
['many', 'fancy', 'word', '', '', '', 'hello', '\t', 'hi']
```

Quoting [`re.split` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. **If capturing parentheses
>   are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are
>   also returned as part of the resulting list.** If maxsplit is nonzero,
>   at most maxsplit splits occur, and the remainder of the string is
>   returned as the final element of the list.

---

**UPDATE** According to question edit:

You can filter empty string out using `filter(None, ..)`:

```
list(filter(None, re.split('(\n|\ +)', 'many fancy word \n\n hello \t hi')))
```

or using `re.findall` with modified pattern:

```
re.findall('\n|\ +|[^\n ]+', 'many fancy word \n\n hello \t hi')
# `[^\n ]` matches any character that is not a newline nor a space.
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt make my requirement clear. Please see update.

Comment: @aitchnyu, `filter(None, re.split('(\n|\ +)', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi'))` give you what you want? (Wrap the result with `list(..)` if you are using python 3.x)

Comment: I think you need to only wrap the space matching pattern in a capturing group.

Comment: yes, it would. I do want a regex result that does not generate `''` though.

Comment: @aitchnyu, Or using `re.findall`: `re.findall('\n|\ +|[^\n ]+', 'many   fancy word \n\n    hello    \t   hi')`

Comment: That works exactly like I intended. How did `[^\n ]` do the trick?

Comment: `[^\n ]` matches any characters that is not a newline (`\n`) nor(?) a space(` `).

Comment: @aitchnyu, if `re.findall` solution works, `filter(None, re.split(..)))` solution should work too.